# How to convert from drawable to int-array

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an int-array like this:

```
private int icons[] = new int[] {R.drawable.itr300, R.drawable.itr3500};
```

But I want to place it in the array.xml.

If I do it like this:

```
<resources>
<array name="icons">
    <item>@drawable/itr300</item>
    <item>@drawable/itr3500</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

---

```
private TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
private int icons[] = images...
```

Now I want to convert Drawable into the int-array. But I don't know how to do it. Can anybody help?

**Comment:**

*I think your answer were useful. But I have not found the answer yet. Can you help me again, to find the syntax errors? I seems good, but I will not work.*

```
   private TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
   private int[] icons = new int[images.length()];  
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length(); i++) {
        icons[i] = images.getResourceId(i, 0);
    }
```

Comment: felixA if you got the answer, please mark the right one as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Using [`getResourceId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getResourceId%28int,%20int%29)

<sub>Hint: Use a loop</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getInt (int index, int defValue)   : Retrieve the integer value for the attribute at index.
```

**Parameters**

**index  Index of attribute to retrieve.**

**defValue  Value to return if the attribute is not defined.**

```
public int getInteger (int index, int defValue)
```

**Parameters**

**index  Index of attribute to retrieve.**

**defValue  Value to return if the attribute is not defined or not a resource**

```
for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

        icons[i]  = images.getInt (i, int defValue) 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't get a working answer. Because of this, I added a comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            row = i.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_menu, parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            row = convertView;
        }

        TextView title = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.menu_title);
        ImageView icon = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.menu_icon);


        title.Text = menuTitle[position];
        //icon.SetImageResource(menuIcon[position]);
        icon.SetImageResource(Icon.GetResourceId(position,-1));

        return row; 
    }
```

Comment: Icon in (Icon.getResourceId) is actually coming from 
TypedArray Icon = context.Resources.ObtainTypedArray(Resource.Array.menu_icon);

Comment: Please add explanation to raise the value of the answer